# Why can I set the class to null and still call methods from it afterwards?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have created the following example code in Java:

```java
public class SetClassNullExperiment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SetMeNull c1 = new SetMeNull();
        c1.setInputToNull(c1);
        System.out.println("Is c1 equal to null? " + Boolean.toString(c1 == null)); // false
        c1.printHelloWorld();

        SetMeNull c2 = new SetMeNull();
        c2 = null;
        System.out.println("Is c2 equal to null? " + Boolean.toString(c2 == null)); // true
        c2.printHelloWorld(); // Throws a NullPointerException (For obvious reasons...)
    }

}

class SetMeNull {

    /**
     * Set the input class equal to <code>null</code>.
     */
    public void setInputToNull(SetMeNull c) {
        c = null;
    }

    public void printHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

Why is it possible to call `c1.printHelloWorld()` after `c1.setInputToNull(c1)` has been called? I would expect a `NullPointerException` when calling `c1.printHelloWorld()`. Why is this not the case? In my opinion, the first four lines (`c1`) are equal to the last four lines (`c2`), but only in the last four lines a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: See this post, it should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1369579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples aren't the same. In the first, you're setting a copy of the reference to `null` (see, e.g. [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3512039/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html)). If you were to call the method on `c` inside `setInputToNull`, you'd get the NPE there.